# Dynamically add elements to fs2.Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

How may I add new elements to fs2.Stream dynamically? For example, I would like to read key pressed as stream. I have tried to build the stream using Stream.eval with a function that use foreverM inside, but it turned out to not be a great idea at all.

Comment: What about using `repeatEval` instead of `foreverM`?

Comment: yes, it is exactly what I have been looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't *push* anything to an fs2.Stream. Streams are lazy, pull-based structures, meaning that the stream asks for next elements on demand.

In this specific case, you can handle that by producing a stream that says "when another element is needed, read console input",

```scala
import cats.effect.std.Console
def readNext: IO[String] = Console[IO].readLine // Or however else
val inputs = fs2.Stream.repeatEval(readNext)
```

---

A more generic solution to pushing elements when it has to actually be a *push* is to use a [Queue](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/queue), and then [create a Stream from the Queue](https://fs2.io/#/concurrency-primitives?id=queue)

---

A third option is to use fs2-io's [built in support for the console](https://fs2.io/#/io?id=console-operations),

```scala
fs2.io.stdinUtf8[F](bufferSize): Stream[F, String]
```